# Unable to login Ubuntu. How can I recover it?

Tags: login, password-recovery

I was trying to setup and ssh server with chrooted and after getting tired of no results and permission issue I ran the following command resulting in a screen that as soon as I enter my user and password revert back to the login screen,

```
sudo chown root:root /
sudo chmod 750 /
```

Is there any way without having to reinstall it to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't logon in you system on any tty?

Restart your system and choose "recovery" in Grub. When it is started you are root and you can try to undo what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand your question clearly. But maybe this could help.

Try logging into the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> (<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>). Insert your username and password.

If success try theses commands:

```
sudo service lightdm stop 
startx
```

If the login still failed usually there will be a log message in the terminal... from that log maybe we can help more.